# Hadoop UI Browse Directory error

Tags: hadoop2

When I open hadoop UI in browsers. I get this error:

```
Path does not exist on HDFS or WebHDFS is disabled. Please check your path or enable WebHDFS
```

[image]

Can you tell me what I am missing and how I can fix this error?

My config:
`hdfs-site.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///opt/volume/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///opt/volume/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

By default, it will auto selct path = '/'. But it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add your JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.sh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).